# How do you modify a filter in Redmine

Tags: redmine

I've installed the Bitnami Redmine stack and have set up some filters for my issues.

I can't for the life of me find how to edit, delete or rename a filter once it has been created.

Any pointers? The Redmine wiki seems to only deal with installation, not usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. When a filter is saved it becomes a 'custom query'.
I was googling for the wrong term

http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/20768?r=22833

'When you select the custom query, there's an edit and delete link in the top corner.'